# Can we update external variable through LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can we update external variable through linq, i.e., can we update a variable which is not being used in linq's scope through a linq?

For example, this is what I tried:

```
var s = list_UIModes_And_Related_Actions_Details
  .Select(x => x.ActionIdList)
  .Select(y => modeAndActionRelationTable[Counter++] = Convert.ToByte(y));
```

But this line doesn't update modeAndActionRelationTable array.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result of doing so? What does your research indicate?

Comment: This question is going to mark as closed. be quick if you want to add anything more for clarification

Comment: What happens if you add `.ToList()` at the end of the last line?

Comment: `modeAndActionRelationTable[Counter++]` is a minefield, beware can lead to unexpected errors

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change any variable inside your LINQ statement, but you should refrain from doing so.

In your example, if you walk over the enumerable `s` twice, `Counter` will go out of bounds. If it iterates only half way, and starts over, `Counter` will be off too. It is just not reliable.

Your code will probably work the first time you materialize the enumerable entirely. Adding `ToList()` or `ToArray()` will do that for you.